# Guardar como copia en Symfony

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine

Estoy intentando crear un formulario que tiene dos botones, guardar como copia y guardar y sobreescribir.

Mis entidades afectadas en el formulario son:
Checklist->ChecklistGroup->ChecklistGroupTask->ChecklistGroupTaskCorrective

Hasta ahora he podido controlar que cuando guarde como copia las nuevas entidades se generen solo en la copia y dejen el original intacto, pero no estoy consiguiendo que me funcione al eliminar.

Este es mi código:

```
public function EditAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $auth_checker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
    $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $checklist = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Checklist')->find($id);

    if (!$checklist) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No se ha encontrado el checklist de id ' . $id);
    }

    $originalGroups = new ArrayCollection();
    $originalTasks = new ArrayCollection();
    $originalCorrectives = new ArrayCollection();

    /** @var ChecklistGroup $group */
    foreach ($checklist->getGroups() as $group) {
        $originalGroups->add($group);
        /** @var ChecklistTask $task */
        foreach ($group->getTasks() as $task) {
            $originalTasks->add($task);
            foreach ($task->getCorrectives() as $corrective) {
                $originalCorrectives->add($corrective);
            }
        }
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(ChecklistType::class, $checklist);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $checklist->setUserModificator($user);
        $checklist->setEstado(true);

        if ($editForm->get('Save')->isClicked()) {
            $em->persist($checklist);
            $em->flush();
        }

        if ($editForm->get('SaveCopy')->isClicked()) {
            $copy = clone $checklist;
            $copy->setNombre($checklist->getNombre() . ' #COPY' . substr(uniqid(), 8, 4) . '#');
            $copy->clearId();

            /** @var ChecklistGroup $newGroup */
            foreach ($copy->getGroups() as $newGroup) {
                $newGroup->setChecklist($copy);
                /** @var ChecklistTask $newTask */
                foreach ($newGroup->getTasks() as $newTask) {
                    $newTask->setChecklistgroup($newGroup);
                    /** @var ChecklistTaskCorrective $newCorrective */
                    foreach ($newTask->getCorrectives() as $newCorrective) {
                        $newCorrective->setChecklistTask($newTask);
                    }
                }
            }

            $em->persist($copy);
            $em->detach($checklist);
            $em->flush();
        }
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Se ha actualizado el Checklist correctamente.");

        return $this->redirectToRoute('listChecklist', array('id' => $id));
    }

    return $this->render(':checklist:create.html.twig', array(
        'edit' => true,
        'form' => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Estoy saliendo loco con este problemilla... cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Comment: Hola, creo que no se entiende bien a que resultado quieres llegar. A que te refieres con "guardar como copia"? pudieras editar tu pregutna y explicarte un poco más?

Answer (score 1):

Para poder guardarte un dato antes de que sea editado puedes usar la función 'prePersist' y 'preUpdate'. 
Ya que se ejecutan antes de almacenar en la base de datos. Puedes guardarte los datos actuales en otra tabla/entity. Te pongo un ejemplo que iría en el Admin:

```
public function preUpdate($entity)
{
    $this->prePersist($entity);
}

public function prePersist($entity){
    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();

    $i18nRepo = $container->get('doctrine')->getRepository("AppBundle:xxx");

    $antiguo = $entity->getAntiguo();

    $buscamos_dato = $i18nRepo->findCa();
    $antiguo->setDato($buscamos_dat);
}
```